# Binding custom entity collection to an ADF table

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0, oracle-adf

I create a method on the session facade, that returns a custom entity collection.
I publish it in the local interface.
I bind corresponding data control iterator to an ADF table.
When run, it shows "No data to display".
There are no exceptions in the weblogic console.

```
public List<Users> getCollection() {
    List<Users> l = new ArrayList<Users>();
    Users u = em.find(Users.class, new BigDecimal(999));
    System.out.println(u.getName());
    l.add(u);
    return l;
}
```

When I invoke this method via another method, bound to a ADF button,
all is fine though.
User name is printed to the weblogic console.

```
public int printCollectionSize() {
    return getCollection().size();
}
```

When I bind to an ADF table a data control iterator created from (autogenerated) method getUsersFindAll, all is fine too.

```
public List<Users> getUsersFindAll() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Users.findAll").getResultList();
}
```

I am completely lost. Is my method never gets executed by the data binding system? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

In ADF all of the code and bindings in the JSP page are simply properties values used for ADF when it begins auto-generating code to link between JSP and the backing bean.  So first and foremost I'm not sure (though I'm no expert) as to whether you can easily bind ADF components to just any collection.

Best bet to start with is to find a way to call a method directly early on that ensures the collection has been initialized, then refresh the table.  Perhaps use a command button with full refresh so you don't have to worry about any PPR oddities.